# Aggregate by fields in _source

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index in elasticsearch with documents that look like this:

```
 "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my-index2",
            "_type": "my-type",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "entities": {
                    "persons": [
                        "Kobe Bryant",
                        "Michael Jordan"
                    ],
                    "dates": [
                        "Yesterday"
                    ],
                    "locations": [
                        "Munich",
                        "New York"
                    ]
                },
                "my_field": "Kobe Bryant was one of the best basketball players of all times. Not even Michael Jordan has ever scored 81 points in one game. Munich is really an awesome city, but New York is as well. Yesterday has been the hottest day of the year."
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to use the aggregate function to aggregate by fields in the `entities` object? I tried this and it didn't work

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "avg_date" : {
            "avg" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source" : "doc.entities.dates"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error said that my index doesn't have an `entities` field.

**EDIT:** With the following term aggregation query:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "dates" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "entities.dates" }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [entities.dates] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index.

I can set fielddata=true like the error says I should however the documentation warns against this because it uses a lot of heap space.Is there another way I can do this query?

EDIT 2: Solved this by setting all fields in `entities` to keywords in the index.

Comment: The dates field is not a numeric field (i.e. `Yesterday`)... how do you expect to run an average on that?

Comment: @val I know. I'm just trying out basic aggregation functions. My target is to count how many documents each term in `dates` occurs in.

Comment: Then you can use the `terms` aggregation, without any script, simply use the field `entities.dates`

Comment: @val Just tried that and got an error. Check my edit please.

Comment: Yes, the `dates` field needs to be of type `keyword`. Glad you figured it out

Comment: @val Thanks for your help :)